# Advice on web services without HTTP

Tags: web-services

My company is planning on implementing a remote programming tool to configure embedded devices in the field.  I assumed that these devices would have an HTTP client on them, and planned to implement some REST services for them to access.  Unfortunately, I found out that they have a TCP stack but no HTTP client.  One of my co-workers suggested that we try to send “soap packets” over port 80 without an HTTP client.  The devices also don’t have any SOAP client.  Is this possible?  Would there be implications if there was a web server running on the network the devices are connected to?  I’d appreciate any advice or best practices on how to implement something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the responses...I implemented a simple WCF service with a WebGet method and used Fiddler to demonstrate how it would work with an HTTP GET request.  I assume when the embedded developer writes a primitive HTTP client it will work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your servers are serving simple files, the embedded devices really only need to send an [HTTP GET request](http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest) (possibly with a little extra data identifying the device, so the server can know which firmware version to send).

From there, it's pretty much a simple matter of reading the raw data coming in on the embedded device's socket -- you might need to only disregard the HTTP header on the response, or you could possibly configure your server to not send it for those requests.

Answer (score 3):

you don't really need an HTTP client per-se.  HTTP is a very simple text-based protocol that you can implement yourself if you need to.

That said, you probably won't need to implement it yourself.  If they have a TCP stack and a standard sockets library, you can probably find a simple C library (such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csoap/)) that wraps up HTTP or SOAP functionality for you.  You could then just build that library into your application.

Answer (score 2):

Basic HTTP is not a particularly difficult protocol to implement by hand. It's a text and line based protocol, save for the payload, and the servers work quite well with "primitive, ham fisted" clients, which is all a simple client needs to be.

If you can use just a subset, likely, then simply write it and be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a trivial http client over sockets (here is an example of how to do it in ruby: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm )

It probably depends what technology you have available on your embedded devices - if you can easily consume JSON or XML then a webservice approach using the above may work for you.